# data from few MySQL tables sorted by ASC

Tags: php, mysql

In the dbase I 've few tables named as `aaa_9xxx, aaa_9yyy, aaa_9zzz`. I want to find all data with a specified `DATE` and show it with the `TIME ASC`.

First, I must find a tables in the dbase:

```
$STH_1a = $DBH->query("SELECT table_name 
                  FROM information_schema.tables
                 WHERE table_name
                  LIKE 'aaa\_9%'
               ");


foreach($STH_1a as $row)
{  
$table_name_s1[] = $row['table_name'];  
}
```

Second, I must find a data wit a concrete date and show it with `TIME ASC`:

```
foreach($table_name_s1 as $table_name_1)
{
$STH_1a2 = $DBH->query("SELECT * 
                      FROM `$table_name_1`
                     WHERE
                           date = '2011-11-11' 
                  ORDER BY time ASC
                     ");

while ($row = $STH_1a2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo " ".$table_name_1."-".$row['time']."-".$row['ei_name']." <br>";
}
}
```

.. but it shows the data sorted by tables name, then by `TIME ASC`. I must to have all this data (from all tables) sorted by `TIME ASC`.

---

Thank You dev-null-dweller, Andrew Stubbs and Jaison Erick for your help.
I test the Erick solution :

```
foreach($STH_1a as $row) { 

$stmts[] = sprintf('SELECT * 
                  FROM %s 
                 WHERE date="%s"', $row['table_name'], '2011-11-11'); 

                     }  

$stmt = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts);  
$stmt .= "\nORDER BY time ASC";  

$STH_1a2 = $DBH->query($stmt);

while ($row_1a2 = $STH_1a2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo " ".$row['table_name']."-".$row_1a2['time']."-".$row_1a2['ei_name']." <br>";
}
```

it's working but I've problem with '`table_name`' - it's always the `LAST` table name.

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

...and the ending solution with all fixes, thanks all for your help, :))

```
foreach($STH_1a as $row) { 

$stmts[] = sprintf("SELECT *, '%s' AS table_name 
                  FROM %s 
                 WHERE date='%s'", $row['table_name'], $row['table_name'], '2011-11-   11'); 

}


$stmt = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts);  
$stmt .= "\nORDER BY time ASC";  

$STH_1a2 = $DBH->query($stmt);

while ($row_1a2 = $STH_1a2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo " ".$row_1a2['table_name']."-".$row_1a2['time']."-".$row_1a2['ei_name']." <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the UNION sql directive:

```php
<?php

$STH_1a = $DBH->query("SELECT table_name
                       FROM information_schema.tables
                       WHERE table_name
                       LIKE 'aaa\_9%'");

$stmts = array();
foreach($STH_1a as $row)
{
    $stmts[] = sprintf('SELECT *, %s AS `table_name` FROM %s WHERE date="%s"', $row['table_name'], $row['table_name'], '2011-01-01');
}

$stmt = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts);

$stmt .= "\nORDER BY time ASC";

$STH_1a2 = $DBH->query($stmt);
```

FIX: Included the table name as returned value.

Comment: Thnks, Eric, it's working, but I've problem with 'table_name' - info above.

Comment: The fix above will return what you want.

Comment: Thnks, I've problem with your fix. Err shows //Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object // to code `while ($row_1a2 = $STH_1a2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
`

Comment: I know the solution, thnks for your help, brgs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing the line as you fetch it from db, gather all data in one array taht you will be able to sort with `usort` and your own callback function.

Other option is to get it sorted directly from mysql, using `UNION` selects like this:

```
$SQL = "
    (SELECT '$table_name_1' AS tbl_name, time, ei_name FROM `$table_name_1` WHERE date = '2011-11-11')
    UNION
    (SELECT '$table_name_2' AS tbl_name, time, ei_name FROM `$table_name_2` WHERE date = '2011-11-11')
    UNION
    (SELECT '$table_name_3' AS tbl_name, time, ei_name FROM `$table_name_3` WHERE date = '2011-11-11')
    ORDER BY time ASC
";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the tables name - it must be generate inside sql procedure.

Comment: That's why I added `'$table_name_3' AS tbl_name` into the select, thanks to that you will have table name in every returned row.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to fix it will be to UNION your selection data as stated in other answers.

A quick fix would be to change your second code block to something like:

```
$Sorted = array();

foreach($table_name_s1 as $table_name_1)
{
    $STH_1a2 = $DBH->query("SELECT *
        FROM `$table_name_1`
        WHERE date = '2011-11-11'
        ORDER BY time ASC
    ");

    while ($row = $STH_1a2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $Sorted[$row['time']] = " ".$table_name_1."-".$row['time']."-".$row['ei_name']." <br>";
    }
}

ksort($Sorted);

foreach($Sorted as $Entry) {
    echo $Entry;
}
```

Note: This will 'fail' for cases where there are multiple entries for one date.